# formatting the citation style so that multiple citations are read 1-3 not 1,2,3

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex

I'm currently using overleaf and for the bibliography part I use the following:

```
\bibliographystyle{ieeetr}
\bibliography{mybib.bib}
```

It does everything nicely except that when I'm citing more than one source, the assigned numbers of the cited references appear as [1,2,3,4,5,6,7].

What do I need to do so that it appears as [1-7]?

Comment: Try adding `\usepackage{cite}` to the preamble of your document.

Comment: Oh wow thank you that was such a quick fix. sorry for not knowing these things

Comment: You're welcome! That's what this site is for.